# Django isn't able to send emails but can login into my gmail acc

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

My Django app is able to log in into my Gmail account, but it is not sending emails.

I know it logged in because I tried sending an email to a non-existing email-address and Gmail gave me this error.

Even looked in my spam folders but nothing :(

[image: Google's Email not found error.]

However, when I manually send an email, it works properly.

This is my SMTP configuration in settings.py

> settings.py

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

I even tried hard-coding and changing the sender's email, but still no result.

I wasn't getting this error a few days before, but for some reason it does seem to be working now.

By the way, I'm using this for password reset functionality.

Comment: did you enable smtp for less secure apps? its a google setting

Comment: @Ejaz I Did turn it on.